# ¿Cómo puedo registrar un ID de forma ordenada en cada registro de un nuevo producto?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches, ando creando un sistema web con PHP usando Mysql cómo base de datos, mi problema es qué necesito que la ID de cada producto no sea repetible, me gustaría que siguieran un orden en especifico dicha ID (0, 1, 2, 3)
Intente buscar alguna solución pero no me fue posible, siempre se registra cómo valor 0 en el campo de Id. Este campo no es utilizado cómo llave primaria.

Mi código a la hora de crear nuevo producto:

```
error_reporting(0);
include('Database.php');

if (isset($_POST['Verificar'], $_FILES['img'])) {

    $nombreInstitucion = $_POST['nombreInstitucion'];
    $direccionInstitucion = $_POST['direccionInstitucion'];
    $correoInstitucion = $_POST['correoInstitucion'];
    $telefonoInstitucion = $_POST['telefonoInstitucion'];
    $nombreImg = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "Instituciones/" . $nombreImg;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO institucion(nombreInstitucion, direccionInstitucion, correoInstitucion, telefonoInstitucion, nombreLogo, rutaLogo) VALUES ('$nombreInstitucion', '$direccionInstitucion', '$correoInstitucion', '$telefonoInstitucion', '$nombreImg', '$destino')";

    if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
        echo "
            <script>
                alert('¡Institución creada!');
                location.href='../Vista/App/Roles/Administrador/Instituciones.php';
            </script>
        ";
    } else {
        echo "
            <script>
                alert('¡Conexión database fallida!');
                location.href='../Vista/App/Roles/Administrador/Instituciones.php';
            </script>
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo más simple sería declararlo como auto incremental y como llave primaria. ¿Por qué dices que no es llave primaria? ¿Hay otra llave primaria? ¿Por qué hay otra?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, gracias por tu rápida respuesta. No está como llave primaria ya que tenía este problema y necesitaba hacer unas pruebas.

Comment: Confirmo que lo propuesto por Cedano sería lo más simple

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevo un poco más de 1 mes trabajando con php día a día :)

Comment: La solución más rápida es crear un campo autoincremental en la base de datos y por cada registro que ingrese a la tabla,dicho registro se incrementa en uno. Si no quieres que el incremento sea automtico, entonces debes crear el campo de tipo Unique INT y consultas el ultimo registro ingresado y le incrementas uno a tu nuevo registro que vas a ingresar.

Comment: *«No está como llave primaria ya que tenía este problema y necesitaba hacer unas pruebas.»* Es que el problema es precisamente porque no has declarado esa columa como llave primaria y auto incremental. A no ser que por otro motivo justificado necesites otra llave primaria. Entonces convendría que expliques el por qué para poder ayudarte de la mejor manera.

Comment: Lo más fácil es hacerlo como dicen los demás modificar la base de datos o salvo que quieras autoincrementar un varchar 0001-2020

Answer (score 0):

Nótese que el problema en este caso no es PHP sino Mysql

Como te han dicho en los comentarios la solución es crear una clave auto incrementada.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

De  esta forma un `INSERT INTO animals(name) VALUES ("cat")` pondría el campo `id` a 1. Y las siguientes llamadas lo irán incrementando.

Otro detalle es que los números enteros tienen un límite.
En este caso `MEDIUMINT` generará hasta `8.388.607` números y luego empezará desde 1 otra vez. Si le decimos que solo habrá números positivos usando `UNSIGNED` entonces dobla el límite `16.777.215`

Aquí tienes la [tabla de límites por tipo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)